# Целостность данных, связи между таблицами

Tags: проектирование, ms-access, связи

Создаю БД "Информация о владельцах автомобилей". Возникла кое-какая проблема...

Есть (в т.ч.) 3 таблицы: **Физ лица, Юр лица и Автомобиль**.
В таблице **Автомобиль** есть поле "Код владельца", для **Физ лица** - "Паспорт", для **Юр лица** - "ОГРН". (Поля ключевые)
Я связываю эти таблицы по этим полям (от "лиц" к Коду владельца), подключая целостность данных и каскадное обновление. Тип связи - один ко многим, естественно.

**Проблема**: когда начал заполнять таблицы, добавил одно Юр лицо. При попытке добавить в Таблицу **Автомобиль** данные по авто у **юр лица**, выходит ошибка, что нарушается целостность данных - Так как нет подобной записи в таблице **Физ лица**. Но её там и не должно быть по сути, так как у авто владелец **ИЛИ** физ лицо, **ИЛИ** юр лицо.

Не знаю, как избежать этой ошибки... Целостность данных, думаю, надо сохранить...

Comment: Не делай две таблицы, делай одну "Владельцы". Ну и пусть часть полей будет использоваться только для одного типа владельца... И да - не делай естественных ключей, уника достаточно, делай синтетику.

Comment: @Akina Хмм... А не будет ли это нарушать нормализацию? Просто у меня эти 2 таблицы совпадают только в (ФИО - Руководитель, ИНН - ИНН). (Но у юр лиц свой ИНН, отличается по факту от физ лиц)...Остальные поля выходит полупустые будут

Comment: Чем это нарушает нормализацию-то? сущность как раз одна - владелец ТС, это ты её нарушаешь, разнося в две таблицы.

Comment: @Akina Вообще мне препод сказал так разбить...Видимо, действительно лучше сделать в одной таблице, хотя пустые поля несколько смущают... А в таком случае поля ФИО - Руководитель стоит объединить? (По факту там указывается ФИО в обоих, но по смыслу они несколько отличаются. Опять же, например, в форме, где будут только Юр лица имеет значение название столбца). P.S. А мой подход был ошибочным (по крайней мере в этой СУБД) или есть какой-то выход?..

Comment: *пустые поля несколько смущают* Чем? *поля ФИО - Руководитель стоит объединить?* Я бы не стал - и дело не в том, что это разные атрибуты, а в том, что у них разный смысл (например, формально ФИО руководителя может меняться хоть ежедневно). *или есть какой-то выход?* Теоретически в подобных случаях обычно применяют либо чистый EAV, либо укрупнённый (отдельные таблицы различающихся атрибутов). А вообще - свобода творчества, ограниченная только необходимостью потом с этой структурой жить...

Comment: @Akina Не хватает квалификации, чтобы объяснить, чем смущает... Остаётся осадок, будто не до конца спроектирован этот "кусок" в том плане, что если поле не используется в ряде случаев, то в этой ли таблице оно должно находиться. Вероятно, я заблуждаюсь...

Comment: Sparse table - вполне обычная штука. И её обычность от СУБД не зависит - разве что у одних с оптимизациями при работе с такими таблицами лучше, чем у других...

Comment: @Akina Большое спасибо за помощь. Про разреженные таблицы обязательно почитаю.